# Lodash sortBy returns elements in random order (not sorted)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, lodash

Lodash sortBy doesn't work for me:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
let array = [3, 'q', 'e', 'w', 4, 'w', 1, 3, 2];
let data = _(array).sortBy(x => x);
console.log(data.value());
console.log(array.sort());
```

output

```
[ 3, 'e', 'q', 'w', 4, 'w', 1, 2, 3 ]
[ 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 'e', 'q', 'w', 'w' ]
```

The output from `.sortBy()` makes no sense. Built in `.sort()` works as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28947253/sort-array-with-lodash-by-value-integer

Comment: @juvian this doesn't answer my question

Comment: It seems as `sortBy` does not sort elements of different types.

Comment: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/688

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the items to a string for comparison

```js
let array = [{a:3}, {a:'q'}, {a:'e'}, {a:'w'}, {a:4}, {a:'w'}, {a:1}, {a:3}, {a:2}];
let data = _(array).sortBy(x => x.a.toString());
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can't because in my actual program values I sort by are properties of the array elements. I've used identity for simplicity here.

Comment: You should update your question with closer list of example items

Comment: This will make example more complex and I also wouldn't be able to use `.sort()` for comparison. My actual values are close to `array.map(x => { foo: x })` and the corresponding sort is `_(array).sortBy('foo')`